# how to change an Int value using ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel

How to change an Integer Value of a composable from another composable using viewModel so that when We navigate to That Composable/screen we should see the changed Value

```
 private var _amt = mutableStateOf<Int>(5)
    var amt: MutableState<Int> = _hanging

    fun changeHangingToFortyFive(){

        amt.value = 45
      
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `private set`, instead of having `private _variable` and `public variable`:

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {
    var amt by mutableStateOf(5)
        private set
    
    fun updateAmt(newValue: Int) {
        amt = newValue
    }
}
```

And in your composable.

```
val viewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()
val value = viewModel.amt
//To update
viewModel.updateAmt(newValue)
```

Comment: why we cannot update variable directly? Instead of using `viewModel.updateAmt(newValue)` this, why we cannot set directly `value.amt = newValue`?

Comment: Is there any relation to SOLID principles?

Comment: @VivekModi In this case you can update it directly, without the setter function but in general the setter/update can contain more logic than a simple update.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should be hoisting the viewModel in a parent composable (probably a NavHost) and pass an lambda expression to update the value of the view model from the child composable.

Example: Passing a callback to some child composable to set the value of view model from there.

```
@Composable
fun parent(viewModel: ViewModel){
    
       
        childComposable(onValueChange= 
                      {changedValue -> viewModel.updateAmt(changedValue}
        )
     

}
```